# Angular - How to fix 'property does not exist on type' error?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lSvgj8ohAI&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXwcl3a6rIfAI7QmGYIkfK5&index=30) ([text version of the same](https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2018/03/angular-5-services-tutorial.html)). I have followed exactly the same code and I am receiving this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'getEmployees' does not exist on type
>   'EmployeeService'

I looked on the Internet and visited many questions on Stack Overflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764043/angular2-property-does-not-exist-on-type), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097820/property-does-not-exist-on-type-object-observable-subscribe), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47356913/angular-2-property-does-not-exist-on-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324949/error-ts2339-property-x-does-not-exist-on-type-y), and so many others issues opened related to this error on GitHub.

**Service:**

```
//import statements go here ...

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
private listEmployees: Employee[] = [
    {
      //just to avoid longer code, deleted dummy data.
    },
  ];

  getEmployees(): Employee[] {
      return this.listEmployees; //ERROR in src/app/employees/list-employees.component.ts(14,44)
  }
}
```

**Component class:**

```
//import statements
@Component({
    selector: 'app-list-employees',
    templateUrl: './list-employees.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list-employees.component.css']
})
export class ListEmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
    employees: Employee[];
    constructor(private _EmployeeService: EmployeeService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.employees = this._EmployeeService.getEmployees();
    }

}
```

I have imported service in `app.module.ts` and added it in providers array of `ngModule`.

I am not able to solve the error neither to understand what is causing this error.

Comment: can you put plunker or stackblitz. That would help to debug your code better

Comment: What's the exact error? Could you post the full error? Don't just add a comment in your code which points people to the line and expect others to know what the error exactly is.

Comment: i have mentioned error in question itself.

Comment: This behavior is also happening with ionic 4 CLI. So if a service is missing it's members restart `ionic serve` will help.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It usually happens when you develop Angular applications. To solve this just shut down the server & start it again:

```
$ ng serve
```

#### Explanation

This happens because when you start the application, The server is actually serving the bundles(JavaScript/CSS/HTML... output files) stored in the dist folder. Sometimes, when you make changes in your code, the changes don't reflect in your bundles, which will lead to the server still using the old bundles.

Comment: i cant believe simple restart would work. i have looked a lot here and there and tried to change code. can you tell why there is such a behaviour?

Comment: @GauravChauhan I'm getting this issue all of a sudden and restarting my IDE and ng serve does not resolve this

Comment: @LennyD Would you post more details so people can look?

Comment: For me the trick was clearing my angular cache before restarting the server.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the compilation warning then the dirty fix would be to make

```
employees: any[];
```

any instances allow any method to call any method on that object. This will avoid compilation warning but it's not runtime safe.

You need to be careful before using it. If you are sure that the method will be available at runtime then only use it.

Answer (score 3):

If all things mentioned above checked, check

`constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService) { }`

private, the access specifier is there. The same issue will occur when access specifier missed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a static keyword in the method declaration:

```
 public static getEmployees(): any []{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also subscribe to the service method instead of saving it to another value in `ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.employees = this._EmployeeService.getEmployees();
}
```

To something like:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.getEmployees()
}

private getEmployees(): void {
    this._EmployeeService.getEmployees()
        .subscribe(fetchedEmployees = > this.employees = fetchedEmployees)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times files are not saved.. So, save all files Or you can close all the files (will prompt you to save..) and build again.. worked for me..