# Property 'updateEmployeeName' does not exist on type 'ContactFormComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular. I am learning about angular forms and though I copied the below code from a tutorial, I still get the error:

> Property 'updateEmployeeName' does not exist on type 'ContactFormComponent'

Typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
})

export class ContactFormComponent  {
  employeeName= new FormControl('');

  updateEmployeeName(){
    this.employeeName.setValue('john');
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<label>
  Employee Name: 
  <input type="text" [formControl]="employeeName">
</label>
```

Comment: Are you intending to make the form in the easier template driven way? Or the reactive form way?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. Can you try to stop your development server and run `ng serve` again? As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884563/angular-how-to-fix-property-does-not-exist-on-type-error), sometimes Angular does not reflect the changes you make during development.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pxyrfx?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

It Doesn't seem like you copy/pasted all the relevant code in your question.
The error you get means that you are using *updateEmployeeName*() somewhere in your code, but all I can see is a declaration of *updateEmployeeName*() inside your ts file.
*updateEmployeeName*() is not used in the html and it is not used in the ts files you posted with your question.
Can you please double check if you used *updateEmployeeName* somewhere else?

Comment: sorry i didn't posted the rest of code:

<p>
  Value: {{EmployeeName.value}}
</p>

  <button (click)="updateEmployeeName()">Refresh</button>

i did called the updateEmployeeName function on button click

Comment: this html in inside contact-form.component.html right ?

Comment: must be something bad going on in your environement, it workd just fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sjhj3g?file=src/app/contact-form/contact-form.component.html

Comment: and don't forget to change EmployeeName.value to employeeName.value