# Angular 15.2.8 error : property does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript

today i create my first project in angular with json-server, when i start my application with ng serve, i get this error :

```
src/app/services/products.service.ts:22:26 - error TS2339: Property 'host' does not exist on type '{}'.
22   let host = environment.host;
```

i try many solutions like restart server or ng build but without any result
project details :
angular version : 15.2.8
CLI : 15.2.7
Node : 18.15.0
npm : 9.5
thank you to take a look at my problem.

products.service.ts :

```
getSelectedProducts():Observable<Product[]>{
  let host = environment.host;
  return this.http.get<Product[]>(host+"/products?selected=true");
}
```

environment.ts :

```
export const environment = {
  production : false,
  host : "http://localhost:3000",
};
```

products.component.ts:

```
products$ : Observable <Product[]> | null=null;

constructor(private productService : ProductsService) {
}

  onGetAllProducts() {
    this.products$=this.productService.getAllProducts();
  }
```

i try many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884563/angular-how-to-fix-property-does-not-exist-on-type-error)
but without any result.

Comment: Can you add the code of the `environment` import in the service?

Comment: @JSONDerulo , of course the import code is already exist in my products.service.ts        import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";